# Git: Pulling other's branches into my local doesn't result in changed files

Tags: git

I want to pull in someone else's work to my local machine. The issue is, though the pulls appear to be successful (no errors), the files do not update.

I have done the following:

```
git branch <their-branch-name>
git checkout <their-branch-name>
git pull origin <their-branch-name>
```

I have also tried

```
git pull

git fetch origin <their-branch-name>

git fetch <their-branch-name>
```

But nothing.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong (all their changes are actually deleted files, does that make a difference)?

Comment: A `git pull` is implicitly a `fetch` and `merge` with the fetched `HEAD`. If your initial checkout of their branch already contained all the deletions, then the files wouldn't exist at all. If your checkout was older, then the `pull` should do a fast-forward merge (i.e. simply move the HEAD) to the latest commit which would presumably include the deletions.

Comment: there are no issues with the first set of command you've tried. if the pull is successful then the changes are already available in your local repo, just refresh the file-explorer/IDE. Still changes are not available, check your **origin URL** and show us the output of **git status**

Comment: What you've done wrong is you haven't show us the output of the commands. (Text, please. Copy/paste from the terminal.)